# Obtain minimum NEGATIVE float value in C++

Tags: c++, stl, floating-point

I was looking at `std::numeric_limits<float>::min/max()` but it appears 'min()' returns the smallest absolute value, not the *lowest* value. Is it safe to use

`-std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`, i.e is float symmetric in min/max limits?

Comment: Is it minimum negative or maximum negative value?

Comment: the _smallest_ number a float can hold. I think that's _technically_ unambiguous since -1 is smaller than 0, but I mean "the negative value with greatest magnitude"

Comment: If your compiler guarantees that you get IEEE 754 floating-point numbers or a good enough approximation, then the set of representable floats is symmetrical and you can use `-std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

IEEE 754 floating point numbers use a sign bit for signed-ness (rather than something like twos complement), so if you're sure that your compiler/platform uses that representation (very common) then you can use `-std::numeric_limits<float>::max()` as you suspected.

Comment: std::numeric_limits::lowest()

Answer (score 30):

use std::numeric_limits::lowest()

```
static _Ty __CRTDECL lowest() _THROW0()
    {   // return most negative value
    return (-(max)());
    }
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/ - it doesn't mention `lowest`, is it standard?

Comment: @John: Yes on C++0x, no on C++98.

Comment: @KennyTM: Thanks. I was clueless on the C++0x part of that.

Comment: @chusbad: I haven't, but your answer is (partly) correct since the version of the standard wasn't mentioned in the question :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `float` is symmetric in minimum/maximum values.

If you're using the lowest representable value as an initial value in searching a list for its maximum value, consider using infinity instead.

`std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity()` will return `true` for any numeric type that has it and `std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` will return a value that always evaluates greater than any other non-NaN value for that type.  This value can be negated and will evaluate less than anything else.