# Largest representable negative floating-point number

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, floating-point, playstation3

What is a platform-independent way of specifying the largest representable *negative* floating-point number?

We found an algorithm that broke when run on a PS3's SPU, but worked fine when compiled for the PPU:

```
float x = -FLT_MAX;
/* stuff */
if (x > 0.0f) {
    // If x is unchanged, code is executed on SPU
}
```

Essentially, is there a well-defined negative equivalent of `FLT_MAX`?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529394/obtain-minimum-negative-float-value-in-c/3529429#3529429). *May* be useful

Comment: Why not use negative infinity?

Comment: Unless the SPU and the PPU have different float precisions, this should work.  I suspect there's a problem in the commented out /*stuff*/ section of your code.

Comment: It's unclear (to me, anyway) what you expect the code to do and what it actually does.  And given how floating point numbers are represented, isn't the negative equivalent of `FLT_MAX` just `-FLT_MAX` (which you're already using)?  Exactly what's not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain minimum NEGATIVE float value in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529394/obtain-minimum-negative-float-value-in-c)

Comment: Why does the code think that `-FLT_MAX` is > 0.0f ? That does not seem to make sense to me!

Comment: @stacker - `FLT_MIN != -FLT_MAX`

Comment: @Blair yes,I expected something like FLT_MIN/MAX 1.17549435e-38f (negative) != 3.40282347e+38f (positive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing what's in /* stuff */, I don't think your problem can be fully addressed here.

There's a good set of slides on the problems inherent in floating point calculation here: http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/pubs/GDC07_Ericson_Physics_Tutorial_Numerical_Robustness.ppt - there may be some hint for you in there as to the source of your problem.

IEEE 754 single precision floating point is not the same on the SPU as it is on the PPU - there's a full explanation in chapter 9 of the SPU ISA document available from http://cell.scei.co.jp/e_download.html which also includes the maximum magnitude of a single precision floating point number.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer -- after reading the linked document detailing the SPU architecture, it became apparent that `-FLT_MAX` wasn't going to work.

Comment: As an aside, the code in `/* stuff */` shouldn't matter, as `x` was only touched in certain conditions that weren't being met; `x` was unchanged by the time we check `x > 0.0f`, which was why there was much head-scratching when it passed!

Comment: Oh, I missed the comment inside the if block. Happy to hear that you've worked it out :)

Answer (score 6):

You want `std::numeric_limits::lowest()`, but it is c++0x only, so not very cross platform at the moment.

You definitely don't want `std::numeric_limits::min()` - that is smallest magnitude, not furthest negative.

If you want something that will always be less than all other doubles, use `-numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`.

Comment: Upvoting, as we do essentially want a very large negative number that is guaranteed to be smaller than anything else.